# Why is full_like so slow (compared to other approaches)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

When I was refactoring my code, I noticed that I wrote a line

```
    class_proba = np.empty_like(self.classes_, dtype=np.float64)
    class_proba[:] = np.NaN
```

so I thought, it would be faster to use [`full_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full_like.html). But since the first rule of performance is "measure everything" (and not just "don't talk about performance") - I did that, and was quite surprised:

```
import numpy as np
import time

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(500):
   np.full_like(np.array([1,2,3]), np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
print(time.time()-t0)

t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(500):
   class_proba = np.empty_like(np.array([1,2,3]), dtype=np.float64)
   class_proba[:] = np.NaN
print(time.time()-t0)
```

results in

```
0.008994579315185547
0.0019996166229248047
```

I was very surprised. Maybe it was the usage of "empty" that made the first part so fast or the wrong type? But even

```
t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(500):
    class_proba = np.ones_like(np.array([1, 2, 3]), dtype=np.float64)
    class_proba[:] = np.NaN
print(time.time() - t0)
```

is faster than using `full_like` with

```
0.003997087478637695
```

and

```
t0 = time.time()
for _ in range(500):
   np.full_like(np.array([1,2,3]), np.nan, dtype=float)
print(time.time()-t0)
```

is (better  but) still not as fast with

```
0.0029981136322021484
```

So my questions is: Why is it so slow to use `full_like` in this case - compared to the other two approaches?

Next I tried to make the array much larger:

```
    a = np.arange(1000000)

    t0 = time.time()
    for _ in range(500):
        np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
    print(time.time() - t0)

    t0 = time.time()
    for _ in range(500):
        np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=float)
    print(time.time() - t0)

    t0 = time.time()
    for _ in range(500):
        class_proba = np.empty_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
        class_proba[:] = np.NaN
    print(time.time() - t0)

    t0 = time.time()
    for _ in range(500):
        class_proba = np.ones_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
        class_proba[:] = np.NaN
    print(time.time() - t0)
```

resulting in

```
1.9398648738861084
1.819936990737915
1.853914499282837
2.292659044265747
```

Can someone explain this as well?

Comment: Here is the source for [`np.ones_like`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L201-L265) and [`np.full_like`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L323-L384). `np.empty_like` seems to be a generated python function (likely written in C).

Comment: Is `time.time()` robust for timing purposes?  I think it might only have a resolution down to some OS tick level.

Comment: It would probably be better to use the `timeit` module in Python's standard library. If you are using jupyter notebook, you can use `%timeit` to time a line or `%%timeit` to time a cell.

Comment: @jakub: I am NOT using jupyter notebook. I am not aware how to use timeit thusly.

Comment: @jakub: It seems that `full_like` is also using `empty` - so the difference commes down to  `multiarray.copyto` vs `[:] = np.nan`... not sure what `[:]` is referencing... I was not able to find the respective code.

Comment: `[:]` means all of the values in the first dimension, so `out[:] = np.nan` means fill the first dimension of `out` with `np.nan`. Because your array is one-dimensional, that overwrites the entire array.

Comment: @jakub: Right, but `multiarray.copyt` does the same, so... what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If the `timeit` module from the Python standard library is used, the performance does not match what was reported in the OP's question. `np.full_like` and `np.empty_like ... out[:]=nan` perform similarly, and `np.ones_like ... out[:]=nan` was slowest.

This makes intuitive sense when considering the number of operations. All of the methods here use `np.empty_like` at their core. `np.ones_like` creates an empty array and then overwrites each value with `1`. `np.full_like` creates an empty array and then overwrites each value with whatever was specified in the `np.full_like` call. It makes sense that `np.ones_like...out[:]=np.nan` is the slowest, because it creates an empty array, fills it with `1`, then fills it with `np.nan`. On the other hand, `np.full_like` and `np.empty_like...out[:]=np.nan` are similar in terms of number of operations, and have almost identical performance.

```
import timeit

timeit.main(
    ["--setup", "import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000000)",
    "class_proba = np.full_like(a, np.nan, dtype=np.float64)"])

timeit.main(
    ["--setup", "import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000000)",
    """\
class_proba = np.empty_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
class_proba[:] = np.NaN"""])

timeit.main(
    ["--setup", "import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000000)",
    """\
class_proba = np.ones_like(a, dtype=np.float64)
class_proba[:] = np.NaN"""])
```

The output is below:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 616 usec per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 619 usec per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 msec per loop
```

Comment: The explaination is making sense. But it is not contradicting with my test with the large array, is it? If you use `timeit` with `np.arange(3)`, you are also getting my results for a small array!

Comment: It does seem similar to your tests with a large array.